# ActionScript 3.0 for loop error 1084

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, flash, loops, for-loop

i'm trying to use for loop in AS3 to get some node's value from an XML File, here's the code with their line after the //

```
function processxml(){
    var checkName               = username.text;
    var checkPass               = password.text;
    users_XML                   = XML(loadusers.data);
    var userid:int;
    var totaldata               = users_XML.*.length();
    var maxsearch               = totaldata - 1;
    var usernamecheck           = users_XML.user[userid].@username;
    var passwordcheck           = users_XML.user[userid].(@username==checkName);
    for (userid=0; userid <= maxsearch, userid++){                      //line 113
        if (usernamecheck==checkName){                                  //line 114
            if (usernamecheck==checkName && passwordcheck==checkPass){  //line 115
                gotoAndStop(2);                                         //line 116
            }else{                                                      //line 117
                result_text.text = "please check your password";
            }
        }else{                                                          //line 120
            result_text.text = "please check your username";
        }
    }
}
```

but it gave me some error like:

```
E:\caservers\actions\main.as, Line 113  1084: Syntax error: expecting semicolon before rightparen.
E:\caservers\actions\main.as, Line 114  1084: Syntax error: expecting identifier before if.
E:\caservers\actions\main.as, Line 114  1084: Syntax error: expecting colon before equals.
E:\caservers\actions\main.as, Line 115  1084: Syntax error: expecting identifier before if.
E:\caservers\actions\main.as, Line 115  1084: Syntax error: expecting colon before equals.
E:\caservers\actions\main.as, Line 116  1084: Syntax error: expecting colon before leftparen.
E:\caservers\actions\main.as, Line 117  1084: Syntax error: expecting identifier before rightbrace.
E:\caservers\actions\main.as, Line 117  1084: Syntax error: expecting rightbrace before else.
E:\caservers\actions\main.as, Line 120  1084: Syntax error: expecting rightparen before else.
```

okay, i REALLY don't have any idea what to check first, because i've done it as what the tutorial said. any enlightenment is very very appreciated! thanks in advance! :D

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You missed semicolon at line with for loop:

```
  for (userid=0; userid <= maxsearch, userid++){
```

should be

```
  for (userid=0; userid <= maxsearch; userid++){
```